# SQL - Only return when no rows hold a value

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle, date

I am looking for a way to return an *ID* only if **NO** rows hold a certain value

For example:

```
*ID* | *Date*    
1    | 01/01/2001      
1    | 02/02/2002    
1    | 03/03/2003
```

If I want SQL to return the *ID* only if no dates are equal to 02/02/2002, how would I script that? I have tried and failed with the below:

```
select *ID* 
from (example)
where date != 02/02/2002
```

The problem is that this still returns the *ID* - 1, as the first and last row do not equal 02/02/2002. What I am aiming for is no returned results because at least one row held the matching date.

I would need the script to completely skip the *ID* when there is a matching date in any row.

For clarity the below should return the *ID* when using the same 'select' as above because no dates are matching:

```
*ID*    |   *Date*
2       |   03/03/2003      
2       |   04/04/2004    
2       |   05/05/2005
```

Comment: Which DBMS? Do you need a cross solution?

Answer (score 2):

You need `Group By` and `Having` clause

```
select ID 
From yourtable 
group by ID 
Having count (case when date != '02/02/2002' then 1 end) = count(*)
```

As mentioned by mathguy, this also works

```
select ID 
From yourtable 
group by ID 
Having count(case when date = '02/02/2002' then 1 end) = 0
```

Comment: Or, more simply, `having count(case when date = 02/02/2002 then 1 end) = 0`.  Of course, the date shouldn't be written as 02/02/2002, but that is a separate issue (I understand you just followed the OP here).

Comment: @mathguy - true.. added as part of my answer

Comment: Thank you very much, you've saved me a lot of trouble here!